# How to extract independent variables from a formula using Rcpp

Tags: r

I am developing a library using Rcpp. I need to extract the independent variables from a formula. I can do this using R but I am unable to do with Rcpp. Say I have the formula Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3

with R I can extract using this.

```
vars<-function(frml){

  temp1 = strsplit(as.character(frml)[3],"\\+")[[1]]

  return(temp1)
}
```

But I want to do it with Rcpp.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A few things: (1) What have you tried so far? (2) Have you looked into `boost::regex`? That's one thing that jumps to mind when I first look at this. (3) **Why** would you want to do this? I ask because when you're looking to do something that's easy in R, but not standard in Rcpp, *sometimes* there can be a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/382734)

Comment: Hi,Thanks.. 
I'm building an R package using Rcpp, so I'm trying to use C++ format as much as possible to make it faster. In my package I'm dealing with dataframes and formulas. Well I've already prepared a R function as above and called that in my Rcpp program succefully. But it would be more useful if it can be done without using R functions.